# Define `Mode: rw` attribute container in Kubernetes MountPath definition

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Currently I am troubleshooting an issue that I have with some points and I found that when I run a container with `docker run` command with the following argument:

`-v /var/run:/var/run:rw`

When I inspect the container I can see the following:

```
{
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/var/run",
    "Destination": "/var/run",
    "Mode": "rw",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
}
```

I can't find the way of set **"Mode": "rw"** inside of the MountPaths / Volume definition of a Pod.

I am using:

```
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run
      name: var-run-mount

  volumes:
  - name: var-run-mount
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run
```

and when I inspect the container, I got this:

```
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/var/run",
            "Destination": "/var/run",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
```

I have tried different combinations and MountPropragation but no one helped to achieve what I am looking for and no one also was able to define that "Mode" attribute.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath

Does someone know if that is possible to be defined?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [access modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) of kubernetes Persistent Volumes.

You can set `accessModes: ReadWriteOnce` for the `hostPath` volume.

***NOTE:*** Unfortunately `hostPath` volume supports only `ReadWriteOnce` accessMode, other modes like `ReadOnlyMany`, `ReadWriteMany` are not supported, as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) in the table.

You need to:

- First create `hostPath PersistentVolume` as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume).
- And then create `persistentvolumeclaim` as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolumeclaim).
- Finally create a Pod referring to that hostPath volume resource as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-pod).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much,

I have tested out but the outcome is the same. It might be because of the `accessMode: ReadWriteOnce` limitation I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Access mode attribute of Persistent Volumes in this [Kub Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) link.

It will define how an external storage environment is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, I have tried out but it didn't work as expected. I got the same outcome.

I am wondering if there is a better storage plugin to use in this use of cases, according to documentation HostPath sounds the right to me.

However, I found something interesting, when specifying at *volumeMounts* level the *readOnly* flag, e.g. :

```
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run
          name: var-run-mount
          readOnly: false
```

I can see the *Mode* is set to 'ro'.

```
{
  "Type": "bind",
  "Source": "/var/run",
  "Destination": "/var/run",
  "Mode": "ro",
  "RW": true,
  "Propagation": "rprivate"
}
```

However trying out the opposite (*readOnly: true*) didn't give the opposite result. (Mode: rw)